How to implement search engine results with rich links like Login and Signup for a SvelteKit app?
I noticed that some apps display enhanced search engine results, where additional links like "Login", "Signup", "Pricing", etc., appear directly below the main link when searching for their app (see the attached example for reference).

I am building an app in SvelteKit and would like to implement something similar. How can I achieve this type of enhanced display in search engine results?
Here are my questions:
What specific techniques or metadata are required to display these additional links under the main result?
Are these links (e.g., Login, Signup) controlled through HTML markup, structured data, or the search engine's crawling behavior?
Is there any specific consideration for SvelteKit apps (e.g., file routing, prerendering)?
I’ve done some research and came across terms like sitelinks and structured data, but I’m unsure how to integrate them correctly in my SvelteKit project.
Would appreciate guidance or examples of how to implement this feature!

These are known as "Sitelinks" - they are automatically created by search engines and website authors have very little control over them.
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/sitelinks
I recommend following SvelteKit's general recommendations for improving SEO, as well as following recommendations for improving Sitelink SEO that would work for any web framework.

https://svelte.dev/docs/kit/seo#Out-of-the-box
https://seo.co/google-sitelinks/

If your website ranks #1 on any search engine for a specific query, you can expect that the search engine will create & manage Sitelinks for you automatically.
